# SELECT returning error but INSERT works

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

When running this code, it returns an error, but only the part of the error code that returns the `$sql` query displays. I get no description of why it doesn't work. The weird part is that `INSERT` does create a new record with the exact same code. Why is this?

I have checked the pivileges on the root user. This user has full access, including SELECT.

```html
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "nny_gamerrum";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT email FROM booking;";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo 'Successfull';
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

echo $conn->error;

?>
```

**RETURNED TO SCREEN:** Error: SELECT email FROM booking;

Comment: From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues): "For successful *SELECT*, *SHOW*, *DESCRIBE* or *EXPLAIN* queries **mysqli_query()** will return a mysqli_result object." That's why your `=== TRUE` is not passing.

Comment: @rickdenhaan I tried `echo mysqli_result()`, but it returned an error stating the object is undefined. I also tried `mysqli_result($conn->query($sql)) but still returning nothing. I read the manual, but can't find an answer.

Comment: Change to `!== FALSE`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "nny_gamerrum";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT email FROM booking;";

if ($data = $conn->query($sql)) {
    var_dump($data);
    echo 'Successfull';
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

echo $conn->error;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php) you can find documentation about query function.
You have error becouse this **$conn->query($sql) === TRUE** statement is giving false.

[Query method](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) return is depends what kind of query you are inserting to it.
For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN methods return **object**, for any other returns **true**

Comment: I've tried this but i cannot seem to get it to work. What is the exact code to get my select into a php variable i can display on screen?